# Spring - Force a bean attribute to come from post variable

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, javabeans

I was wondering how to force spring to populate an *autowired* bean from POST data (instead of GET).
The problem is that I have a form mapped to a bean (i.e. a class with only setters and getters) which is processed thanks to a @RequestMapping function like :

```
@RequestMapping("/my/custom/url")
public String myFunction(HttpSession session,
    HttpServletRequest request,
    @ModelAttribute @Valid MyBean bean,
    Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
```

So to explain the problem, let's suppose I have a variable A in MyBean. If I send it through a GET parameter (*/my/custom/url?**A=foo***), The *bean* is populated with it's value which it shouldn't be (imho).

How can I fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stop `GET` requests from hitting this method, you need to specify which http method you want to accept (`GET` is the default if you don't specify):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/custom/url", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

`GETs` will now be rejected; only `POSTs` will hit your method.

It sounds like you also need to use the `@RequestBody` annotation too:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/custom/url", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String myFunction(HttpSession session,
    HttpServletRequest request,
    @RequestBody MyBean bean,
    Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
```

`@ModelAttribute` works for `GETs`: binding the values in the URL string into your bean (like you showed).

But, for posts, Spring needs to bind the *body* of the post to a bean, which is slightly different: hence the `@RequestBody` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can force spring to only accept POST requests for a method, so in your case it will be:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my/custom/url", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String myFunction(HttpSession session,
  HttpServletRequest request,
  @ModelAttribute @Valid MyBean bean,
  Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
```